# Access the base class method with derived class objects

Tags: c#

If I am using shadowing and if I want to access base class method with derived class objects, how can I access it?

Comment: can you clarify the question and add some code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First cast the derived class object to base class type and if you call method it invokes base class method. Keep in mind it works only when derived class method is shadowed.

For Example,

Observe the commented lines below:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        string a = "Base method";
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new void Method1()
    {
        string a = "Derived Method";
    }
}

public class TestApp
{
    public static void main()
    {
        DerivedClass derivedObj = new DerivedClass();
        BaseClass obj2 = (BaseClass)derivedObj; // cast to base class
        obj2.Method1();  // invokes Baseclass method
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the best example/explanation. Thank you so much!

Comment: erm MPD much?! lol. And, could you explain how this answer is better than the others, trivial answers?

Comment: This was very helpful. I am using a parent/base class for water meter records whose information is spread across several tables. I don't need virtual routines to set and get account number and suffix (the suffix appends the account for each meter attached to the account), because these values use does not change between the data in each table. So having the base class contain the data and methods makes more sense.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Based on the timestamps, it appears that 3692 was actually thanking Oded for their edits to this answer.

Answer (score 23):

Use the [`base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword:

```
base.MethodOnBaseClass();
```

> The **base** keyword is used to access members of the base class from within a derived class:

Comment: Have an upvote. You **even** edited the non-answer by a self congratulary OP to make it... look like something. You deserve a special purpose badge (SecondMile or Ascetism come to mind)

Comment: @sehe - Thanks for the upvote, even it is on a trivial answer (and I appreciate I am only getting upvoted here because the OP is being... juvenile).

Comment: what if Base class is interface ?

Comment: @atp_09 - I don't follow. A base **class** cannot be an interface, by definition. If you are **implementing** an interface (there is no "inheriting" from an interface - it is just similar syntax), you are not *deriving* from it.

Comment: Here is how I meant. I have a base class (an interface) and derived class is  inheriting the base class (by syntax " class Derived: IBase"). The problem  I am facing right now is - there is a method in interface which is implemented in derived class (with syntax : IBase.Method(){implementation}. Is there a way to access this method from derived class ?

Comment: An **interface** doesn't have an implementation. There is no code to derive from. Again, @atp_09 - why would you need to "access" something that has no code/implementation? When implementing an interface `class Derived: IBase` (where `interface IBase` is the interface being **implemented**), there is nothing to access. You really need to read up on what interfaces are and what the `class Derived : IBase` actually means vs a `class Derived : Base` (where base is an actual `class` - abstract or otherwise).

Comment: @BKSpurgeon - change the protection level? Likely private by default, need to make it protected.

Comment: @Oded yup that was it :)

Answer (score 9):

You qualify the method call:

```
base.foo();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DerivedClass derivedObj = new DerivedClass(); 
(derivedObj as BaseClass).Method1(); // cast to base class with method invoke
```

Comment: Hah :) Why the heck didn't I think about this?